# Elastic search geo distance filter with or condition

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation

I am a newbie to elastic search. How can we add geo distance filter in "should", I tried to use below query it failed to execute.

```
GET /availabletrucks/_search{  "query" : {

  "bool": {
  "must":     { "match": { "EntityType": "DeliveryTrucks" }},
  "should": [
              { "match": { "OriginState": "TN" }},
              { "match": { "IsDestinationBoundaryNull": "true"   }},

               "filter" : { "geo_distance" : {                "distance" : "100miles",
            "OriginCoordinate" : {
                "lat" : 36,
                "lon" : -89
            }
        }  }  
  ]
}  }}
```

I want to create a elastic search query like below SQL

```
SELECT * FROM Trucks WHERE EntityType = 'D Trucks' AND ( state = 'TN' OR Isdestination = 0 OR Location.Stdistance (@orgin) > 100)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you,

Subin

Comment: this part "OriginCoordinate" looks wrong - possibly it needs to be "OriginCoordinate.location". Can you update your question to include; your mapping, your data, the error you get back?